# Feature engineering for timeseries dataset in Python

Tags: python, feature-extraction

I have a dataset with `n` observations, where all the observations have `m` timesteps. I also have a `n*m` array which contains the label for each timestep on each given observation.

I am doing feature engineering on this dataset to find meaningful features in the data, according to the labels I have. Is there any Python package out there to facilitate this process?

I came across `tsfresh` (https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh), although it seems like it's only intended to be used when we have a single label to classify each observation, and not a label to classify each timestep, as is my case.

Comment: Hi, I am the author of tsfresh. Can you clarify your data in more detail? (Maybe with a screenshot or a short sample), then I can tell you if tsfresh is the right feature engineering tool for your case.

Answer (score 9):

You could try [Featuretools](https://www.featuretools.com). It is an open-source automated feature engineering library that explicitly deals with time to make sure you don't introduce label leakage.

For your data, you could create two entities: `"observations"` and `"timesteps"`, and then apply `featuretools.dfs` ([Deep Feature Synthesis](https://www.featurelabs.com/blog/deep-feature-synthesis/)) to generate features for each timestep. You can think of an entity as being the same as a table in a relational database.

Of particular usefulness for your problem would be the Cumulative primitives in Featuretools, which are operations that use many instances ordered by time to compute a single value. In your case, if there was a observation with multiple timesteps each with a certain value, you could calculate the mean value of the previous timesteps using the [CumMean primitive](https://docs.featuretools.com/generated/featuretools.primitives.CumMean.html?highlight=cummean).

Here is an example:

```
from featuretools.primitives import Day, Weekend, Percentile, CumMean, CumSum
import featuretools as ft
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
timesteps = pd.DataFrame({'ts_id': range(12),
                          'timestamp': pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1/1/2018', freq='1d', periods=12),
                          'attr1': np.random.random(12),
                          'obs_id': [1, 2, 3] * 4})
print(timesteps)

       attr1  obs_id  timestamp  ts_id
0   0.663216       1 2018-01-01      0
1   0.455353       2 2018-01-02      1
2   0.800848       3 2018-01-03      2
3   0.938645       1 2018-01-04      3
4   0.442037       2 2018-01-05      4
5   0.724044       3 2018-01-06      5
6   0.304241       1 2018-01-07      6
7   0.134359       2 2018-01-08      7
8   0.275078       3 2018-01-09      8
9   0.499343       1 2018-01-10      9
10  0.608565       2 2018-01-11     10
11  0.340991       3 2018-01-12     11


entityset = ft.EntitySet("timeseries")
entityset.entity_from_dataframe("timesteps",
                                timesteps,
                                index='ts_id',
                                time_index='timestamp')
entityset.normalize_entity(base_entity_id='timesteps',
                           new_entity_id='observations',
                           index='obs_id',
                           make_time_index=True)

# per timestep
cutoffs = timesteps[['ts_id', 'timestamp']]
feature_matrix, feature_list = ft.dfs(entityset=entityset,
                                      target_entity='timesteps',
                                      cutoff_time=cutoffs,
                                      trans_primitives=[Day, Weekend, Percentile, CumMean, CumSum],
                                      agg_primitives=[])
print(feature_matrix.iloc[:, -6:])


       CUMMEAN(attr1 by obs_id)  CUMSUM(attr1 by obs_id)  CUMMEAN(PERCENTILE(attr1) by obs_id)  CUMSUM(CUMMEAN(attr1 by obs_id) by obs_id)  CUMSUM(PERCENTILE(attr1) by obs_id)  observations.DAY(first_timesteps_time)
ts_id
0                      0.100711                 0.100711                              1.000000                                    0.100711                             1.000000                                       1
1                      0.811898                 0.811898                              1.000000                                    0.811898                             1.000000                                       2
2                      0.989166                 0.989166                              1.000000                                    0.989166                             1.000000                                       3
3                      0.442035                 0.442035                              0.500000                                    0.442035                             0.500000                                       1
4                      0.910106                 0.910106                              0.800000                                    0.910106                             0.800000                                       2
5                      0.427610                 0.427610                              0.333333                                    0.427610                             0.333333                                       3
6                      0.832516                 0.832516                              0.714286                                    0.832516                             0.714286                                       1
7                      0.035121                 0.035121                              0.125000                                    0.035121                             0.125000                                       2
8                      0.178202                 0.178202                              0.333333                                    0.178202                             0.333333                                       3
9                      0.085608                 0.085608                              0.200000                                    0.085608                             0.200000                                       1
10                     0.891033                 0.891033                              0.818182                                    0.891033                             0.818182                                       2
11                     0.044010                 0.044010                              0.166667                                    0.044010                             0.166667                                       3
```

This example also used “cutoff times” to tell the feature computation engine to only use data prior to the specified time for each “ts_id” or “obs_id”. You can read more about cutoff times on [this page](https://docs.featuretools.com/automated_feature_engineering/handling_time.html) in the documentation.

Another cool thing that Featuretools lets you do is construct features per observation in the “observations” table, instead of per timestep. To do this, change the “target_entity” parameter. In the following example, we use take the last timestamp per observation to use as the cutoff time, which will make sure no data is used from after that time (e.g. data from obs_id = 2 at 2018-01-11 will not be included in the Percentile() computation for obs_id = 1, with cutoff time 2018-01-10).

```
# per observation
ocutoffs = timesteps[['obs_id', 'timestamp']].drop_duplicates(['obs_id'], keep='last')
ofeature_matrix, ofeature_list = ft.dfs(entityset=entityset,
                                        target_entity='observations',
                                        cutoff_time=ocutoffs,
                                        trans_primitives=[Day, Weekend, Percentile, CumMean, CumSum])
print(ofeature_matrix.iloc[:, -6:])

        PERCENTILE(STD(timesteps.attr1))  PERCENTILE(MAX(timesteps.attr1))  PERCENTILE(SKEW(timesteps.attr1))  PERCENTILE(MIN(timesteps.attr1))  PERCENTILE(MEAN(timesteps.attr1))  PERCENTILE(COUNT(timesteps))
obs_id
1                               0.666667                          1.000000                           0.666667                          0.666667                           0.666667                      1.000000
2                               0.333333                          0.666667                           0.666667                          0.666667                           0.333333                      0.833333
3                               1.000000                          1.000000                           0.333333                          0.333333                           1.000000                      0.666667
```

Lastly, it is actually possible to use tsfresh in conjunction with Featuretools as a "custom primitive". This is an advanced feature, but I could explain more if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tips. Can you please explain more for PERCENTILE variables. I dont know how exactly we can create these variables. let's say I have some history data, how come I calculate PERCENTILE for new data in the future ?

Answer (score -1):

I could answer more in detail if you give me more details about the question. However, based on my understanding, you want to predict something with the time-series data that you have.

There is a package called `keras` in Python for machine learning. What you can do is, you can use LSTMs for training your model. The support for LSTMs is very good in `keras`.

Comment: That sounds like a buzzword answer, you propose to use LSTMs without understanding application of OP. Also, the support for 1dim LSTMs is not good (yet) in keras. If OP wants to classify those time series, LSTMs are NOT the right tool